# Wildcards as parameters in snakemake?

Tags: parameters, wildcard, snakemake

I just got into snakemake and I have been stuck with this for a while:
I have this rule where I would like to use elements of a list (stored from a file) as parameters. This is the closest I got to it but it does not work.

```
#configfile: 'config.yaml'
proteins = list(x.strip().split()[1] for x in open(config['protein_ids']))
rule links:
params:
    prot = lambda wildcards: proteins[wildcards.protein]
shell:
    'esearch -db protein -query {params.prot} | elink -db assembly -target nuccore | efetch -format docsum | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element Caption,Title >> genomes.txt'
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'protein'
Wildcards:
```

Any hint would be very appreciated!
Best,
D.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Snakemake.

At least some of your problem is not defining an output.  Maybe something like this would work:

```py
# configfile: 'config.yaml'
proteins = list(x.strip().split()[1] for x in open(config['protein_ids']))

rule links:
    output: '{protein}_genomes.txt'
    params:
        prot = lambda wildcards: proteins[wildcards.protein]
    shell:
        'esearch -db protein -query {params.prot} | '
            'elink -db assembly -target nuccore | '
            'efetch -format docsum | '
            'xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element Caption,Title '
            '> {output}'
```

That will throw an error becauce `proteins` is a list and it seems like you are using it as a dict.

Generally, appending to files with snakemake isn't a good idea because snakemake works through files and modification times.  There's no way to know if a file needs to be rebuilt when you are appending to it.  It's better to add another rule to concatenate all the files.

Finally, for long commands I like to split the shell directive over multiple lines to make it easier to read and modify.  The shell contents are treated like they are in a block and get concatenated together.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips! I also tried to modify the params line so that now I use the list: `prot = lambda wildcards: proteins` but then the command will try to run with the entire list at once (`Command 'esearch -db protein -query WP_136129796.1 WP_136130620.1 WP_159990234.1 WP_136132112.1 WP_136131313.1 WP_095034915.1 WP_006708696.1 PAV05377.1 WP_015873789.1 WP_100096494.1 | elink -db assembly -target nuccore | efetch -format docsum | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element Caption,Title > genomes.txt' returned non-zero exit status 255`) any ideas?

Comment: I also tried to use `prot = expand('{protein}', protein=proteins)` with no success. It also tries to use the entire list at once.

Comment: Do you just want to query the protein?  `prot = lambda wildcards: wildcards.protein`? Otherwise edit your question to clarify your intent.